# Confused on MainActivity.java again

Tags: android

So I'm still fairly new to Android Studio and programming in general and I'm trying to follow this course by Udacity. The problem is that in MainActivity.java all it says in mine is

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    // ...
}
```

while they have more Override Methods such as `OnOptionsItemSelected`, etc. I believe I was told by them to set it to "Blank Activity", which I believe is "Empty Activity" now, and I think the problem is the updates that have been made since there video had been made and now, but I'm just looking for a solution for this. Any help would be appreciated. I hope I am making sense here Thanks.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are confused on. You can safely delete the onCreateOptionsMenu methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is "Basic Activity" instead of "Empty Activity" and you should be able to continue following the tutorial.

If they have the xml files and java files available, once you copy and paste it should look the same as well.

Comment: When I made the same project with Basic Activity, there was a lot more in the first Override method than what they had in their video, would it still work the same?

Comment: yep, you'll just get extra UI elements that they won't really touch on.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you didn't really know about Android's coding framework, and need to read some example or tutorial.

I'm not have any relation about the following site, but as my point of view, it's a good Android coding tutorial.

[Android - Hello World Example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_hello_world_example.htm)

Answer (score 0):

OnOptionItemSelected is a callback method which handles menus.

You only need the onCreate callback method in order to display a sample *Hello world!* and then follow the Udacity course.

You can erase the others if you have created a blank activity instead of an empty one.